# How can we calculate the constants of the SIR model?

Tags: population-genetics, population-dynamics, population-biology, epidemiology

I am not a biologist by profession, but I am attempting to implement a simple SIR model from the following [paper](https://www.academia.edu/23561826/NUMERICAL_SOLUTION_OF_STOCHASTIC_EPIDEMIOLOGICAL_MODEL_CASE_OF_SIR_MODEL). The paper assumes the following constants are known:

**rc**    = growth rate of susceptible group S

**k**     = carrying capacity of susceptible group in absence of infection

**alpha** = max value of per capita reduction rate of S due to I

**a**     = half saturation constant

**gamma** = natural recovery rate from infection

**delta** = death rate of recovered population

I found some coronavirus data from the following [source](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases), and I plotted the Italy data in particular:

[image]

- ***Can I calculate the constants above from this type of data?***
- ***Is it a good assumptions for these "variables" to be constant?***

Here is my attempt of the model with the constants given in the paper

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE].  Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome Are you an administrator- can you migrate it please? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not and so don't have that level of access. Is there some reason you can't copy this and post on that site (and then delete from this site)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question about mathematical modeling rather than biology.